# Cannot understand ij term in TangoPoseData

Tags: java, device, google-project-tango

I have been working on Google Tango device from last week. And I was successfully able to display them in web browser using threejs library. But I have only used xyz from the TangoPoseData class. I am not aware of "ij" what does that mean? Also I am trying to implement an algorithm for converting 3d points to triangle mesh using those xyz 3d co-ordinates. So before making an algorithm I would like to know these things or any suggession for making mesh would be great.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you are interested in TangoXyzIjData, rather than TangoPoseData which doesn't have "ij".  Pose data is for location & orientation of the device and XyzIj is point clouds for objects visible by Tango. Please clarify which of the two you are interested in using.

Comment: Please tidy your tags. You've used [[tag:google-project-tango]], which matches your question and [[tag:tango]], which is about a software library for the D language, and is completely irrelevant to your question. When tagging, _read the tag description_ before grabbing a tag.

Comment: @Aaron Roller well actually i am going to make the 3d model from the google tango device and I got only points right now I will have to write lots of codes for making it 3d mesh by matching neighboring points. I think TangoXyzIjData is the main one i need

Answer (score 1):

TangoXyzIjData is used to understand the depth.  The z component provides meters from the device to the point being observed.

These points don't come in any particular order so the ij provides a way for the developer to organize the points in a table so you may know which points being observed are next to another (not available from the xyz data alone).

More importantly the ij portion of the XyzIjData is not yet implemented as mentioned in the [known issues](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/known-issues):

> The IJ buffer of the XYZij struct is under development and not yet populated via the API.

So you shouldn't concern yourself with IJ data since it isn't working yet and there is plenty more to understand.

Comment: So it means i cannot use ij  :(  I was thinking of making the 3d model from those points and making triangular mesh by those points.

Comment: @privatejava hi, did you found a way of creating a mesh from XYZij?

Comment: sorry for late response but i was able to generate mesh by using the threejs and it was not that pretty, may be i had not done much polishing . It has been quiet few years that i had given up that project.